# What free utility can I use to test LAN performance and quality?

Tags: local-area-network, qos, test

I want to test a LAN for speed and reliability, I wanted to use qcheck but it won't instal on any of our XP systems. What other tool could I use? Is there anything with voip tests that is free? Does anyone have a link to an older version of qcheck even? What standard tools would you suggest that do not test voip specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iperf is an example of many LAN speed testers.